# Comparing "axiomatized function spaces"

Tags: lo.logic, gn.general-topology, real-analysis, universal-algebra

*This was previously [asked and bountied](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3619809/28111) at math.stackexchange with no response. I've also tweaked the language for clarity; see the edit history for the broader context, and note that the existing answers were aimed at the earlier version of the question.*

---

Let $C(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$ be the space of all continuous functions $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with the compact-open topology, and consider the following two subspaces:

- $\mathcal{Asso}$ = the subspace of all **associative** functions.
- $\mathcal{Comm}$ = the subspace of all **commutative** functions.

Of course these are distinct as sub*sets*; my question is whether they are topologically distinguishable:

> Is $\mathcal{Asso}\cong\mathcal{Comm}$?

I strongly suspect that the answer is negative - in particular, $\mathcal{Comm}$ is connected and I suspect $\mathcal{Asso}$ is not - but I don't see how to prove this. (Another nice feature of $\mathcal{Comm}$ is that it is an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space in a natural way; however, it's not clear how to extract any power from this observation.)

Generally, $\mathcal{Asso}$ seems rather mysterious, and I'm interested in any information about it.

Answer (score 8):

The following result from Section 6.2 of János Aczél's classic book [Lectures on Functional Equations and their Applications](https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/mathematics-in-science-and-engineering/vol/19/suppl/C) seems to be closely related, and the long list of references on the solutions of the associativity equation (p.253/4) may provide further entry points into the literature. (Although that list is way out of date, with the book being from 1966.)

---

**Theorem:** Let $f \in C(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$ satisfy the associativity equation
$$f(x,f(y,z)) = f(f(x,y),z).$$
Suppose moreover that $f$ is cancellative, i.e. that
$$
f(x,y) = f(x,z) \quad \Rightarrow \quad y = z,
$$
and similarly in the other argument. Then $f$ is conjugate to addition $+ : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ via a monotone homeomorphism. In particular, $f$ is commutative.

---

It seems plausible that this result can be used to prove that if your theory $T$ consists of associativity and the cancellativity laws, then $T_{\mathbb{R}}$ is homemorphic to the space of monotone homeomorphisms $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. But I haven't worked out the details.

Comment: +1 - although that doesn't answer the question, it's a very neat observation (and the reference is great, I'd never heard of that book).

Answer (score 2):

Here are some functions in the connected component of the associative function $f(x,y)=x$.

**Proposition:** If $f(x,y)=g(x)$ and $f$ is associative, then there is an interval $[a,b]$ (possibly infinite on either side) such that
$$g(x)=x \text{ for all }x\in [a,b]$$
$$g(x)\in[a,b]\text{ for all }x\in \mathbf{R}$$
Furthermore all such $g$ produce associative $f$.

**Proof:** By associativity, $g(g(x))=g(x)$. So if $y$ is in the range of $g$ then $g(y)=y$. Then let $a=\inf(range(g))$ and let $b=\sup(range(g))$. The other direction is trivial. $\square$

So in any case, the connected component of $f(x,y)=x$ is substantial. As an easy example, the function $f(x,y)=x$ is the limit of $f_n(x,y)=\max(n,x)$.

It seems plausible to me that these associative functions are disconnected from the ones that depend on both variables. If so, the associative subspace would be disconnected.

Comment: I think there is a path between the projection functions $(x,y)\mapsto x$ and $(x,y) \mapsto y$. Consider the one-parameter family of continuous associative functions $f_t(x,y)=\max(\min(x,\tan(\pi t/2)),y)$ with $−1<t<1$, which form a path between $f_{−1}(x,y):=y$ and $f_1(x,y):=\max(x,y)$. By symmetry there is another path between $f_1(x,y)$ and $(x,y)↦x$, so we may take the composition of these two paths.